# Particle.io waitFor() function similar to that of system

Tags: c++, arduino, particle.io

I am using `Particle.io` firmware version 2.1.0, and I am attempting to make a function as a member of a class that will take one parameter, `int waitForDuration` and will loop until either the public member of the class has changed to value `true` or the duration has expired with the value remaining `false`. I have tried to write a function like this, which I will provide below, and this function works as expected for a few calls and eventually it will no longer wait for the boolean, instead return false immediately. If anyone can provide any insight on what is happening/why that would be appreciated. Thanks!

## Files

### MyClass.h

```
#ifndef MyClass_h
#define MyClass_h

namespace MyClass
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public:
            bool publicFlagMember;
            bool waitForFlag();
    }
}
```

### MyClass.cpp

#### Function that I have previously tried

```
bool waitForFlag(uint16_t timeout)
{
    uint16_t timer = millis();
    while (millis() - timer <= timeout)
    {
        // call Particle.process() to ensure that when the variable changes we catch it
        delay(200);
        Particle.process();
        if (publicFlagMember)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is this multithreaded or how can `publicFlagMember` be changed while you are waiting in `waitForFlag`? If it is multithreaded, you need to synchronize your reads/writes to the variable. If it's a variable that is somehow changed in IRQ routines, you should make it `volatile`. Also, you have a declaration for a member function named `waitForFlag` and a definition of a free function named `waitForFlag`. These two are not connected. You could also simplify the wait loop: `uint16_t timer_end = millis() + timeout; while (millis() < timer_end) { ...` - You should probably use a wider type though

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, this program is multithreaded. While the `waitForFlag()` function is executing, the flag in question will be changed by another function in another thread.

Comment: Then you need to synchronize the access to the variable somehow. You could try to make it atomic, if your arduino library has support for atomics. Instead of `bool publicFlagMember;` you `#include <atomic>` and declare the variable as  `std::atomic<bool> publicFlagMember;`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I should note something else that I have tried with the same amount of success, so failure is creating a `volatile static bool`. I will look into atomic tomorrow, however I don't believe the OS has support for `std`

Comment: What thread library do you use?

Comment: @TedLyngmo That ones a little tricky, I will link the docs discussing threads in the particle.io ecosystem https://docs.particle.io/cards/firmware/system-thread/system-threading-behavior/

Comment: Ah, ok. You then need to read [ATOMIC_BLOCK()](https://docs.particle.io/cards/firmware/system-thread/atomic_block/) and [Synchronizing Access to Shared System Resources](https://docs.particle.io/cards/firmware/system-thread/synchronizing-access-to-shared-system-resources/) and possibly [Waiting for the system](https://docs.particle.io/cards/firmware/system-thread/waiting-for-the-system/) which seems to be one of particle.io's built-in condition waiting mechanisms.